# Which graph does NOT represent sequence graph?

Tags: sequences-and-series, graphing-functions

I have 4 graphs and should choose which ones are NOT sequence graphs.

[image]

The first is a constant sequence graph, eg. a(n)= 2.

The second is not a sequence graph, because it is a sinus function.

The third is a sequence graph, eg. a(n) = -3+n.

The fourth - I am not sure, but I think it is not.

Thx for reply.

Comment: What is your definition of a "sequence graph"

Comment: I think the fourth graph is a sequence. Let $t, t'\in \mathbb{Z}$ be fixed, then $a(n)= -(n+t)^{2}+t'$. For example if $t=-1$ and $t'=-3$ we have $a(n)= -(n-1)^{2}-3$. So your graph satisfy in this sequence formula.

Comment: Why should the second one not be considered a sequence graph?  Just because it extends to the left as well?  There are such things as double-sided sequences.  The terminology you use is not universally known and so without you defining it for us it is impossible for us to answer, but if I were to guess as to a definition I would say that all of them or all but the second are possible sequence graphs.

Comment: My best guess as to the definition of a "sequence graph" would be that it is a graph of a sequence, a sequence here being defined as a function with domain $\Bbb N$ (*or in the case of two-sided sequences, a function with domain $\Bbb Z$*).  That is an incredibly loose definition, and so there is no reason to say any of the pictured (*except the second in the case you insist the domain must be $\Bbb N$ and not $\Bbb Z$*) are not in fact graphs of a sequence.

Comment: Yea, those sequences are led by natural numbers, so the second one cannot be sequence.

Comment: sequence of real numbers is a function which gives index n(natural numbers) just one real number a(n) from real numbers

Comment: @JMoravitz I think it does not satisfy that fourth graph, because numbers go like (-3,-4,-7,...)

Comment: That is hardly rigorous or convincing.  There are many sequences other than the basic ones like arithmetic sequences (straight lines) or geometric sequences (exponential curves).  It is perfectly allowable for a sequence to repeat, go negative, change direction, be difficult to predict, etc...  there is nothing suggesting from the image alone that the fourth is not a sequence